# What is transaction(Process ID 116 )deadlocked on Lock?

Tags: sql-server

I got below error message from application:

> Transaction(Process ID 116 ) was deadlocked on Lock | communication
>   buffer resources with another process and has been  chosen as the dead
>   lock victim. Return the transaction.

I have read the blog 
"https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/16/sql-server-fix-error-1205-transaction-process-id-was-deadlocked-on-resources-with-another-process-and-has-been-chosen-as-the-deadlock-victim-rerun-the-transaction/"

But I want to know what is (Process ID 116) and what cause of error?

Regards,

Rahul.

Comment: Its the sessionid that ran the transaction at the time. you can run  dbcc inputbuffer(116), this will find the query that ran.

Comment: Can you post the sample code and scenario details? It can help us to understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rahul, this indicates the session_id. If you are familiair with Adam Machanic's sp_WhoIsActive, you can run that. Or download it at http://whoisactive.com/.

Apart from your specific problem, this stored proc provides a lot of nice insights, including blocking info and other diagnostic info.This might help you check the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

What is (Process ID 116)?

**SPID in SQL Server is a Server Process ID**. These process ID's are essentially sessions in SQL Server. Every time an application connects to SQL Server, a new connection (or SPID) is created. Process ID 116 is nothing but SPID 116

USE `EXEC sp_who2` for finding all sessions in SQL server.

What cause of error??

> Deadlock occurs when any two SQL server process IDs are locking a
>   separate resource and each one of them is trying to access the
>   resource locked by the other process.

**Fix/Resolution:**

- Try to use SQL server profiler to Analyze Deadlocks. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188246.aspx
- In each script that has a transaction(locking) invoived, Begin the transaction as late as possible and commit it as soon as possible.
- Try to set the optimal lock time value depending up on your script.use [@@LOCK_TIMEOUT](http://sqlserverlearner.com/2012/using-lock_timeout)
- SET the DEADLOCK_PRIORITY value in each script so that the priority processes wont be deadlocked.Use [SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY](http://sqlserverlearner.com/2012/deadlock_priority)
- Use query hints for each TSQL Query.
  Use `WITH NOLOCK` in select statements (when the waiting/locking is not needed)